# How could I change a textcoroul or a background colour of a TextCell in a ListView on condition

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wonder, how could I change a colour of textcell in a listview by condition. It doesn't matter if it a background color or a textcolor, I just want to highlight some rows depending on condition. My code example below.

```
  <ListView x:Name="lstData" HasUnevenRows="false" Footer="Footer" ItemSelected="OnSelection" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding OrderId}" Detail="{Binding OrderState}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,5,5,5">
          <Button Text="New Order" Clicked="OnNewOrderClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>
  </ListView>

    public ManageOrder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vList = App.orderDatabase.GetAllOrders();
        lstData.ItemsSource = vList;

        for( int i=0; i < vList.Count(); i++ )
        {
            if( vList[i].IsDispatched == false )
            {
        // **Change colour of text view**
            }

        }        
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to do it by DataBinding as well. Have a look at `ValueConverters` or the Template Selectors

Comment: Thanks! Template Selector helped a lot, I tried ValueConverter before but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstData" HasUnevenRows="false" Footer="Footer" ItemSelected="OnSelection" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding OrderId}" Detail="{Binding OrderState}" TextColor= "{Binding StateColor}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,5,5,5">
          <Button Text="New Order" Clicked="OnNewOrderClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

And in the Order (which is your vlist has)  I would have a property with a that is of type Color (the one that is inside xamarin.forms library) which you can control.

Comment: Thanks, but I already used Template Selector and that what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using Template Selector.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
You can achieve your requirement by using IValueConverter.

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:Class1 x:Key="class1" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="lstData">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding OrderId}" TextColor="{Binding Colors, Converter={StaticResource class1}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

//Converter class

    public class Class1 : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((int)value > 1000)
                return Color.Green;
            else
                return Color.Red;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```